# How can I get the power indicator to show battery percentage based on the maximum capacity?

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, macbook-pro

This morning, I took my 2011 MBP running Ubuntu 16.04 off the charger. As you know, macbook chargers have a small LED on them, which is either orange or green, depending on the current battery status. As it had been on all night, it was green, indicating at least 95%.

However, when I turned it on, I noticed that unity's battery indicator displayed only 71%. This was odd, but I've had some issues with it in the past, so I wasn't surprised.

After answering some emails, I decided to investigate on the battery percentage issue. By this time, it was showing 60%. `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` gave the following:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                bq20z451
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 22 Dec 2017 08:17:08 AEDT (64 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
  present:             yes
  rechargeable:        yes
  state:               discharging
  warning-level:       none
  energy:              37.3614 Wh
  energy-empty:        0 Wh
  energy-full:         45.76 Wh
  energy-full-design:  63.1815 Wh
  energy-rate:         14.9139 W
  voltage:             11.517 V
  time to empty:       2.5 hours
  percentage:          60%
  temperature:         32.6 degrees C
  capacity:            72.4263%
  technology:          lithium-ion
  icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
  1513891028    60.000  discharging
  History (rate):
  1513891028    14.914  discharging
```

Using a percentage calculator, I found that the displayed 60% was 37.36Wh out of the original ~63.1Wh. How can I make ubuntu calculate percentage from the current maximum energy of ~45.7Wh? Right now at 60%, it *should* display 82%.

Edit: It's been on almost all day, and it's now displaying 73%, or `46.1105 Wh`, which is what `energy-full` is also now displaying, meaning the overall capacity has gone down by 0.6Wh :(

Comment: Ignore my last comment.  I read your question a couple more times here.  I am thinking you might need to download the source code for the indicator and change where it is calling to the `energy-full-design` to call the `energy-full` instead.  I will see if I can download the source too.

Comment: Good thinking. Where would one get that?

Comment: Okay. I'll see how I go and report back.. 

EDIT: returns `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`
EDIT2: Source is at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/indicator-power/trunk.16.04/files

Comment: I can't find `energy-full` anywhere in the [/src/](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/indicator-power/trunk.16.04/files/head:/src/) section. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70646/discussion-between-doofitator-and-terrance).

Comment: Haha okay, thanks. For those who come and see this, the following is what I attempted to put into a chat: _"There is a lot of reference to power, as oppose to energy, but I'm kind of at loss with C code. I'm a web developer, so it's not exactly what I'm used to looking at." "I can't tell, but does this code also control the brightness and volume overlays?"_

Comment: Google searching around about this indicator, it actually looks like it is a bug.  I would have to go look for all the findings I had again.  But there are many that think the same way you do about the percentage of the charge.  However, maybe you can look into creating your own indicator:  http://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html   Here's one of the bugs:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/1471087

Comment: Hmm. Okay thanks. I'll look into that and see how I go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've built my own.

Thanks to the handy links from Terrance, I've built a small python script that solves this issue, and hosted it on Github:

[Project Page](https://github.com/Doofitator/Doofitator-Power)

Comment: The github.com/Doofitator/Doofitator-Power is now 404 not found.